# What are Google in-app billing responses positive and negative to test and handle?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I'm putting in-app billing into my app, and I've been following the trivial-drive example. However, the example doesn't list all possible responses sent by Google. In the example, it test for NOT Response_OK; but doesn't provide info if user canceled the purchase, or if there was a loss in connection during the purchase process.

So my question is, what are the possible situations and negative responses to test for and handle? I want to provide feedback to the user as to what the problem was.  Also how likely is it to receive a **BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR** and what could be a possible causes, the API is a bit vague about this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All responses from IAB Google server can be checked [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)

One of the responses is `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` which means as `Network connection is down`
and another is 'BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED' which means user cancelled the purchase flow

You will just be able to know these responses and AFAIK, trivial drive app already checks for these responses

Comment: I got to dig a bit deeper in the example and looking at the link you provided.  I found that the trivial drive example handles the responses but doesn't report anything other than fail, not-fail.  So it doesn't indicate clearly what to report back to the user as to the type of fail.

Comment: You can always customize what you need to show to user based on error codes